# Nancy cannot load with wildcard url reservations

Tags: wildcard, nancy, netsh

I have a desktop application that is self hosting a NancyFX web server. Being a desktop application there is a requirement that we allow dynamic IP addresses so we have registered the url using the wildcard option with netsh, as so:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/ user=Everyone
```

However when this application is run under a non-administrator account the following exception is thrown.

```
The Nancy self host was unable to start, as no namespace reservation existed for the provided url(s).

Please either enable UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically on the HostConfiguration provided to 
the NancyHost, or create the reservations manually with the (elevated) command(s):

netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.90:1234/ user=Everyone
```

I have tried many combinations of wildcard registrations, all with the same result. I also looked at registering the wildcard when loading Nancy, but due to Nancy using Uri types this was not valid.

I was under the assumption that by using the wildcard registration I had registered any ip address to be used. But Nancy seems to need the specific ip address registered.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell my why the wildcard registration will not work with Nancy, or even better, how to make it work with Nancy.

Comment: This is a .NET issue as far as I know. Try hosting with Owin using nowin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nowin/ this fixed my issue with self hosting without admin privilages.

Comment: Thanks Phill, I'll try and give Owin a go.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but if anyone runs into this, Nancy SelfHost allows you to create Url reservations automatically using the **HostConfiguration** object.

The Url is then reserved automatically on startup.

```cs
//Nancy configuration
HostConfiguration hostConfig = new HostConfiguration()
{
    UrlReservations = new UrlReservations()
    {
        //create URL reservations automatically
        CreateAutomatically = true
    }
};

//Uri
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9999");

using (var host = new NancyHost(hostConfig, uri))
{
    host.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Running self-hosted server ...");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to close the application.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```